# Is it a bad practice to use stateful components bypassing redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say, I don't want to keep my checkboxes state in global redux store. Cause I don't want to deal with actions and reducers for this small local state. So I want to explicitly use `setState()` inside my component.

Is it a bad practice (for instance, in testing aspect)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on component state vs Redux state](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state):

> Using local component state is fine. As a developer, it is your job to determine what kinds of state make up your application, and where each piece of state should live. Find a balance that works for you, and go with it.
>
> Some common rules of thumb for determing what kind of data should be put into Redux:
>
> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
> - Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already there instead of re-requesting it)?

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely fine to keep the checkbox state in you local state as long as it doesn't depend on the data.

A good practise is to keep all you data in your redux store and the ui-related state in you local store.